# How to append a class at the end of the class DOM

Tags: javascript, angular, dom

Hi I have the following lines of code,

```
for ( let x: number = 0; x < this._vcr.element.nativeElement.querySelectorAll(".ui-steps-item").length; x++) {
            let className: any = this._vcr.element.nativeElement.querySelectorAll(".ui-steps-item")[x].className;
            if(className != 'ui-steps-item ui-state-highlight'){
                this._vcr.element.nativeElement.querySelectorAll(".ui-steps-item")[x].className += " btn-disable";
                console.log(className);

            }
            // console.log(this._vcr.element.nativeElement.querySelectorAll(".ui-steps-item")[x].className);
        }
```

basically am getting the dom elements with class name `.ui-steps-item`, and am appending a new class named `btn-disable`. But somehow the first dom element's class is not changing with the new class. Any idea guys? Also how can I append the class after a particular dom element? Thanks in advance guys

Comment: What about using bindings like `[class.btn-disable]="..."` instead?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [**classList**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList) property.

`classList.add` will alllow to update the current class on the element